# Programmatically change Size of Table

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, programmatically-created

The Storyboard: http://s7.directupload.net/images/140717/z5hwmezv.png

Hey guys,
Ive got an app that recursively triggers a the same tableview controller (lets say there are files and folders in it) until you trigger a file instead of a folder. When a file is clicked, it jumps into the GLKit View Controller.

Now I want to resize the tableView programmatically, which wont work. I already got the window size, which I'm going to use for calculation the position and size of the tableView:

```
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

I tried different ways to change the size like the following, which dont change anything.

```
mainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

It works If I programmatically create the mainTableView, but then my segue gets deleted and I did not found any solution to create a segue programmatically.

It would be great if you can help me to find a solution that works with a storyboard tableView.

Comment: if your storyboard is using Autolayout then you'll need to influence the constraints NOT the frame.

Comment: Is this a UITableViewController or just a UITableView inside of a UIViewController?

Comment: mainTableView is a UITableView inside a UIViewController:

@interface CustomersList : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
}

Comment: Autolayout is checked btw.

Comment: Play with the Autoresize Subviews or Clip Subviews in the storyboard.

Comment: uncheck autolayout in storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Add delegate UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate

```
@interface viewController: UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
   UITableView *tableView;
}
```

Step 2:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
tableView=[[UITableView alloc]init];
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(10,30,320,400);
tableView.dataSource=self;
tableView.delegate=self;
tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[tableView reloadData];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];

}
```

Step 3: Properties for tableview

```
//-- For table sections

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 1;
}

//-- For no of rows in table

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 10;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

//-- Table header height if needed

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 50;
}

//-- Assign data to cells

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;

   if (cell == nil)
   {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
   cell.textLabel.text=[your_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ***(or)*** cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
   return cell;
}

//-- Operation when touch cells

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Your custom operation
}
```

Comment: How does this answer attempt to answer the OP's question?

Comment: Please add table view programatically. So I mentioned the way.

Comment: Hey Nazim, thanks for your answer. I created the tableView programmatically. But now I got the problem, that my two segues where deleted as well. I dont know how to create a segue without the table in my storyboard :/

Comment: I undid the deleting of the table and shrinked it to 0 height in the storyboardcontroller. Its now behind the programmatically created table and all segues are working fine. Not the perfect solution, but it works i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pic makes me think your CustomerListVC is a UITableView subclass which means the tableview is the root view and if you are using a UINavigationController based flow then you can't resize the root view readily.

What you can do is place the UITableView in a container and manipulate its constraints from the controller.

first change

`class CustomerListVC : UITableViewController`

to

`class CustomerListVC : UIViewController`

next throw away the Customer List instance in `Interface Builder` and drag in a new `UIViewController` instance instead. Xcode doesn't like you changing the base class of its stock objects.

make the new `UIViewController` instance a `CustomerListVC` type `FileOwner` and drag a `UITableView`  into the content view.

Set  edge constraints and add outlets to the constraints in your view controller.

[image]

From there play with the table as you see fit. e.g

```
-(void)squishAtBottomLeftAnimated:(BOOL)animate {

    CGFloat animateTime = animate? 0.5:0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animateTime animations:^{

        self.topEdgeConstraint.constant = 400;

        self.bottomEdgeConstraint.constant = 5;

        self.leadingEdgeConstraint.constant = 5;

        self.trailingEdgeConstraint.constant = 200;

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I Chose the solution of Nazim because it required less modification :)